# Cannot Load the file using getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, file, classpath, avro

I am trying to learn Apache Avro and I have started with simple tutorial for Avro. I am trying to use a JSON Schema to load the data. Below is my Simple example-

```
public class AvroExample {

    public static Schema SCHEMA; // writer's schema
    public static Schema SCHEMA2; // reader's schema

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String[] mails;
    private AvroExample boss;

    static {
        try {

            SCHEMA = Schema.parse(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("Employee.avsc"));
            SCHEMA2 = Schema.parse(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("Employee2.avsc"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't load a schema: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // some more code

}
```

But somehow this line, always give me exception-

`SCHEMA = Schema.parse(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("Employee.avsc"));`

as- `Couldn't load a schema: java.lang.NullPointerException`

I believe somehow, it is not able to load the file properly or I am loading the file in a wrong way.

This is the file content-

```
{
  "type": "record", 
  "name": "Employee", 
  "fields": [
      {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "age", "type": "int"},
      {"name": "emails", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "string"}},
      {"name": "boss", "type": ["Employee","null"]}
  ]
}
```

Below is the picture of my workspace which shows where I have put those two avsc files-

[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Put a `/` in front of your path string. As to why that works, read the javadoc for `Class#getResource()` and the linked methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the project setup you've shown us, your classpath will likely look like

```
/root
    /Employee.avsc
    /Employee2.avsc
    /com
        /rjamal
            /avro
                /test
                    /AvroExperiment
                        /...
```

In other words, the two `avsc` files will be at the root of the classpath. The method call

```
AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("Employee.avsc")
```

looks for the resource in the package the `AvroExample` class is in.

To make it relative to the root of the classpath, prefix your path with a `/`.

```
AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/Employee.avsc")
```

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the **absolute name** of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:  **modified_package_name/name**
>
>   Where the modified_package_name is **the package name of this object** with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios for the suggestion. I learned a new thing today. But after making that change, still I am getting the same exception. `SCHEMA = Schema.parse(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/Employee.avsc"));
   SCHEMA2 = Schema.parse(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/Employee2.avsc"));`

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T Are those files in `src/main/java` or inside some package? Follow maven conventions and put your non java files in `src/main/resources`, which should be a source folder in Eclipse.

Comment: They are not in any package. It is exactly as shown in the image. But in general what's the best way? Where we would be putting these files? And also I created another file `config.properties` and put it in the same exact place. And after that I did something like this- `System.out.println(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
   System.out.println(AvroExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/Employee.avsc"));` So the first one printed out the `java.io.BufferedInputStream@1160116` but the second printed out as null.

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T The conventional place for non-java resources in a `Maven` application is in `src/main/resources`. Put those files there. What you just posted above should be telling you that something is off, either the name of the files doesn't match or they aren't actually there.

Comment: It is strange. If I am creating a new file with different names and copying the exact content from Employee.avsc file to that new file, then it works fine.

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T It's possible Eclipse's state was corrupt.